# connecting android app with php and mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to connect an android app to a php script on a local wamp server so that i can authenticate the user.Everything is fine except that the android app cannot connect to the server.What might be the problem?No error is displayed.
Here is the code block from where am trying to connect to the server.

```
try{
            response=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/login.php",postParameters);
            res=response.toString();
            res=res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            if(res.equals("0")) {
                userverified=false;
            }
            else {
                String usern=username.getText().toString().trim();
                //session.createLoginSession(usern,res);
                userverified=true;

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            flag=true;
            //error.setText(e.toString());
            }
```

The result is the exception being called.
The exception is   java.net.socket Exception:Permission denied

Comment: in the `catch` bloack, print the stacktrace. it might help to solve your problem.

Comment: The IP does not seem to be an ip in your local network. Check the ip. It looks like if you are using a virtual machine. Reconfigure the virtual machine to get an ip from the dhcp of your local network. Do not use Shared Connection.

Comment: @quidage, it is ip for local networks made by Mac OS X.
mungaih kamau, show us stacktrace of your exception. Show us the message from Exception.

Comment: I have added the exception

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to include permissions in the manifest file.One needs to include the uses internet permission in the manifest.